# Why do my under the cabinets lights dim after they are on for a short while?

Tags: lighting

I bought a house that has under the cabinets LED lights.  One of the units go on normal and bright but after about 10 minutes begins to dim.  they never go completely off (or I've not let them on long enough to do so).  I turn the unit off and later turn it on and it is bright but begins the same cycle.

Comment: Are they getting hot?  It's possible they are intentionally dimming to stay within a thermal limit, in which case you'd need to mount them in a way that they can cool better.

Answer (score 2):

The internal power supply, probably a 120V to 12V stepdown transformer, is starting to go. It is probably located at the end of the fixture and it's doubtful you would be able to fix it. Best bet is to replace the fixture.

Comment: It's quite possible the power supply unit can be replaced separately. They are often external, or readily available modules.  Case in point most IKEA stuff.

Comment: I do agree it is probably the supply, depending on the type built in or separate brick style makes the difference, a separate brick you might have an old charger that would work or good will for a dollar, built in usually replace. One of the most common driver chips cost almost what the lamp costs in some cases.